# Wamp rewrites url automatically?

Tags: php, apache

I am facing some issues with url rewrite on windows wamp. The problem is whenever i access below urls

```
http://localhost/test/index

or 

http://localhost/test/index.php
```

It loads the home page. The problem is that wamp automatically hides php extention from urls, even after disabling mod_rewrite module.
I'm also not using .htaccess file.
This is very strange behaviour, This is the first time i got this issue.

```
Softwares:
        - WAMPSERVER 64BIT - 3.1.4
        - PHP Version 7.2.10
        - Apache Version 2.4.35
```

**httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
# Virtual Hosts
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    #Require local
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Any solution to turn off this automatic rewrites, so that i can do it myself via htaccess file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share the virtualhost configuration.

Comment: @VikashPathak - Added file.

Comment: @VikashPathak - Thanks for pointing out vhosts file, solved the error.

Comment: Awesome @Kim! You deserve self-lerarner badge

Answer (score 2):

**Finally solved the problem. The problem was with wamp 3 software, it uses +MultiViews directive by default.**

**To solve the problem just replace,**

```
Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
```

**with**

```
Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
```

**Hope it helps someone!**